# Of Bash loops and if statements

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I need to look at a line, and perform a quick if/then->echo on it depending on the content of column 3.

The file looks like this:

```
name network subnetmask
net_A 192.168.0.0 24
net_b 10.10.0.0 16
```

Some columns also have a blank 3rd column, and I need to have an if/then for those as well.

Psuedo-code should look like this in my mind:

```
snet_mask=`cat $filename | grep -i net | awk '{print $3}`
if [ $snet_mask = 24 ]
then
awk '{print "something"$1,"something else"}'
fi
if [ $snet_mask = 23 ] 
then
awk '{print "something"$1,"something else"}'
fi
```

etc

That just doesn't work it seems, since $snet_mask becomes the value of "all" of $3, so I think I need a for loop based on grep -i net, however I don't really know.

What's the right answer? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one-liner :

```
awk '$1 ~ "^net" && $3==24{print "something", $3, "something else"} $1 ~ "^net" $3==23{print "something", $3, "something else"}' file.txt
```

Or on multi-lines (easier to read) :

```
awk '
     $1 ~ "^net" && $3==24{print "something", $3, "something else"}
     $1 ~ "^net" && $3==23{print "something", $3, "something else"}
' file.txt
```

We can do it simply like this too (depends of your needs) :

```
awk '
     $1 ~ "^net" && ($3==24 || $3==23) {print "something", $3, "something else"}
' file.txt
```

Or even simpler & shortest with a regex :

```
awk '
     $1 ~ "net" && $3 ~ "^2[34]$" {print "something", $3, "something else"}
' file.txt
```

Comment: Wow, that's so much easier. Thank you

Comment: Added "net" match (missed that part)

Comment: Quick question sputnick - if we had to add an else statement (IE $3 is blank), how would I add in the 'else' to that string?

Answer (score 1):

you could accomplish what you need in an awk statement, since you're already using awk

```
cat $filename | grep -i net | awk '{if($3==24) print $1; else print $0;}'
```

In the if statement (if 3rd col is 23), I'm printing just the first column, otherwise I'm printing everything. Obviously you can expand this to work with all of your cases

Comment: Thanks Brett - looks to be about the same as sputnick's. Since he beat you to the punch I'll go with his, but here's a +1 :)

Comment: `awk '$1~"net" {if($3==24) print $1; else print $0;}' $filename`
That is a bit cleaner, was just using the code from the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Staying in bash without external tools, you could do something like this:

```
while read name network netmask ; do
    if [[ "$name" == net* ]] ; then
        case "$netmask" in
            "") echo "It's empty" ;;
            24) echo "It's 24" ;;
            23) echo "It's 23" ;;
             *) echo "None of the above" ;;
        esac
    fi
done < "$filename"
```

Comment: Oops, showing my age there. It's true of sh that quotes around filenames in redirections are not needed, but not of bash, so, yes, you are correct that the quotes should be used. (Years ago I was actually castigated for using them, but that's changed...)

Comment: I wonder what `sh` that was, I tried it in classic Bourne shell without quotes and I got an "ambiguous redirect" error. The quotes are on the other hand not required around the variable on the lefthand side inside the double square brackets nor around the variable in the case statement.

Comment: Actually, if you start bash as /bin/sh, it obeys the old parsing rules at least on Linux. (I checked and it worked when my shebang was `#!/bin/sh` but not with `#!/bin/bash` - bash emulates sh when it's started through the sh link.) It's standard on classic sh - variables associated with with < and >, or between case and in, are not subject to splitting after expansion. (My sh flavors in the past included AIX, SunOS, HP-UX.)

Comment: I must have made a mistake, and used bash on Solaris instead, because I just retried it with Solaris' classic Bourne shell `/bin/sh`, with `/usr/xpg4/bin/sh`, with `ksh88` `ksh93`, with `bash --posix`, with `dash` and `zsh` and they all behaved like you said. Only `bash` needed the double quotes..